# VBA 2042 Type mismatch - #N/A - Array

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I would have a problem in creating an array, which contains a number of data, which then will be merged into one file. During reading the info from the files, then having them put into the another merged file, the loop in which it is situated it find a 2042 error. I found in Add Watch that it wants to give back #N/A as the function in the original file does not returns anything. How can I avoid my macro stopping? I have found ways to skip this record, but I cannot insert it into my current loop because of insufficient experience in handling these. It stops at here  "If aOutput(1, outputCol) = aDataFromPivotFiltered(1, filteredCol) Then" See below a small bit of the macro.

```
For outputCol = 1 To UBound(aOutput, 2)
    For filteredCol = 1 To UBound(aDataFromPivotFiltered, 2) 
        If aOutput(1, outputCol) = aDataFromPivotFiltered(1, filteredCol) Then 
            For filteredRow = 2 To UBound(aDataFromPivotFiltered, 1) 
                aOutput(filteredRow, outputCol) = aDataFromPivotFiltered(filteredRow, filteredCol)
            Next filteredRow
            Exit For
        End If
    Next filteredCol
Next outputCol
```

I have found the below, which would be ok, but it is applied another macro.

```
 Sub Test()
    Dim varIn As Variant
    [a1].FormulaR1C1 = "=NA()"
    If IsError([a1].Value2) Then
        varIn = "skip record"
    Else
        varIn = [a1].Value2
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there anyone who could help me with this? It keeps causing headaches not matter how many article I am reading in this topic. Cannot figure out.

Comment: When you build this array `aDataFromPivotFiltered` skip the cells that have errors in the formula.

Comment: Hello Scott, yes, I would like to skip them, but how to code it into my current cycle?

Comment: could you find out the error description. Use Error handler, For eg "On Error Goto errOut:"... more on http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm. If you want to continue the cycle, one could use "On Error Resume Next"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for errors first, like below:

```
If Not IsError(aDataFromPivotFiltered(1, filteredCol) And Not IsError(aOutput(1, outputCol)) Then 
    If aOutput(1, outputCol) = aDataFromPivotFiltered(1, filteredCol) Then 
        For filteredRow = 2 To UBound(aDataFromPivotFiltered, 1) 
            aOutput(filteredRow, outputCol) = aDataFromPivotFiltered(filteredRow, filteredCol)
        Next filteredRow
        Exit For
    End If
End If
```

This way, any formula errors that are passed into the array will be skipped.